# Head pose estimation opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, head, estimation

I have a specific question with regards head pose, I am looking into 
creating a cylindrical model that maps 2D points to this 3D model,
and then compare points from successive frames using optical flow,
so that later on I can perform pose estimation.

I discovered that opencv has a warp function
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/stitching/doc/warpers.html#detail::CylindricalWarper : public detail::RotationWarperBase

I also have read that OpenGl might be used for this.

I think what I am looking for is a texture map, but here is an example of what I am looking for....

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Etj_aktbnwM

Any guidance would be much appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tutorial to get you started:

http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/03/19/quick-and-easy-head-pose-estimation-with-opencv-w-code/

I have modified this code in one project to create a realtime head pose tracker. The initial feature points were detected autmatically, and tracked along the frame sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Totoro, I end up trying a direct method for estimating the pose, considering the motion as rigid body motion, maybe during the final step after I have estimated the motion I think then manipulating a 3d object to illustrate the motion would be nice. I haven't used pnp or posit before though, so I am wondering would it be possible to directly feed values for the pose and create a model lets say. Peace.